# Typescript interface union with different properties

Tags: typescript

I have an object with three possible properties:

```
consistencySelector = {
  transaction: "kkjk4k45kjlkf";
  newTransaction: {};
  readTime: "sometime";
}
```

I would like only one property to be present at any time using the following definitions:

```
interface Transaction {
  transaction: string;
  newTransaction: never;
  readTime: never;
}

interface NewTransaction {
  newTransaction: object;
  readTime?: never;
  transaction?: never;
}

interface ReadTime {
  readTime: string;
  transaction?: never;
  newTransaction?: never;
}



type consistencySelector = Transaction | NewTransaction | ReadTime;
```

Must I make optional `never` properties for every branch or is there a more elegant way to achieve the same result? for instance if  `consistencySelector` had 20 properties

Comment: The current question title of your question is too generic to be helpful. Please edit to the site standard, which is for the title to simply **state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

No you don't use 'never' rather you don't include properties that aren't relevant at all.

```
interface Transaction {
  transaction: string;
}

interface NewTransaction {
  newTransaction: object;
}

interface ReadTime {
  readTime: string;
}

type consistencySelector = Transaction | NewTransaction | ReadTime;

cs: consistencySelector = {
  transaction: "kkjk4k45kjlkf";
  newTransaction: {};
  readTime: "sometime";
}
```